# In an existing web app, how do I introduce restricted access to groups of users?

Tags: design-patterns, mvc, asp.net

I'm working on a large web application.  Users are organized into Companies, then Roles, and then possibly Teams or are individual users.  For example, Bob is a member of Company A, has the Officer role, and is on Mary's team.

Our development team is tasked with adding the ability to restrict access to various features, as well as within groups.  I've taken a look at [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/121188/how-to-implement-restricted-access-to-application-features) which suggests that features be granular and there's a mess of switches somewhere.

We'd like to avoid this, as our existing feature set and planned feature set is very, very large.  We'd like to come up with an extensible pattern for managing this sea of features and in the future adding even more.

In this scenario, **How do I introduce the concept of feature access to an existing web application?**

Answer (score 1):

I also take the opposite view to the answer you quote. Rather than allow access per feature, which end up with each user having a large table of access rights, assign blocks of features to a limited number of roles.

This can require some push back and discipline, as managers will naively ask for users to 'only be able to do x'. But in terms of maintaining and reporting or security it is far superior